# Move label of an angle in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've proudly produced the following figure, with your help.
But there is a detail that is not fine: the theta2 label has to be moved. I know how to move labels on a line but not in this case. How does it work?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usetkzobj{all} % not necessary with the last versions
\usepackage{subcaption}

%\usetkzobj{all} only once
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
 \begin{scope}[thick,font=\scriptsize]
    \draw [->] (-.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node [above left]  {$\operatorname{Re} z$};
    \draw [->] (0,-.5) -- (0,4) node [below right] {$\operatorname{Im} z$};
  \end{scope}
  \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (z1) at (4.511,1.642);
  \coordinate (z2) at (2.143,2.553);
  \coordinate (pr) at (1.368,3.759);
  \coordinate (x) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (y) at (0,1);
  \draw (o) -- node[above,shift={(.4cm,.1cm)}] {$r_1$} (z1) node [right] {$z_1$};
  \draw (o) -- node[above,yshift=.2cm] {$r_2$} (z2) node [right] {$z_2$};
  \draw (o) -- node[above,yshift=1cm] {$r_1{\cdot}r_2$} (pr) node [right] {$z_1\cdot z_2$};
  \draw pic[draw, "$\theta_1$", ->, angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius = 1cm] {angle = x--o--z1}; 
  \draw pic[draw, "$\theta_2$", ->, angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius = 1.5cm] {angle = x--o--z2}; 
  \draw pic[draw, "$\theta_1{+}\theta_2$", ->, angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius = 2.5cm] {angle = x--o--pr}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use `tkz-euclide`? `TikZ`is enough !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The text pic text has the option `text pic options`. Here, simply move the text up to the left to avoid overlapping on the side `z_1`of the  angle.

```
pic text options={shift={(-3pt,3pt)}}
```

I took the liberty of colouring the different angles, which in my humble opinion makes the figure easier to read.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
 \begin{scope}[thick,font=\scriptsize]
    \draw [->] (-.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node [above left]  {$\operatorname{Re} z$};
    \draw [->] (0,-.5) -- (0,4) node [below right] {$\operatorname{Im} z$};
  \end{scope}
  \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (z1) at (4.511,1.642);
  \coordinate (z2) at (2.143,2.553);
  \coordinate (pr) at (1.368,3.759);
  \coordinate (x) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (y) at (0,1);
  \draw (o) -- node[above,shift={(.4cm,.1cm)}] {$r_1$} (z1) node [right] {$z_1$};
  \draw (o) -- node[above,yshift=.2cm] {$r_2$} (z2) node [right] {$z_2$};
  \draw (o) -- node[above,yshift=1cm] {$r_1{\cdot}r_2$} (pr) node [right] {$z_1\cdot z_2$};
  \draw pic[draw,red, "$\theta_1$", ->, angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius = 1cm] {angle = x--o--z1}; 
  \draw pic[draw,blue, "$\theta_2$", ->, angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius = 1.5cm,pic text options={shift={(-3pt,3pt)}}] {angle = x--o--z2}; 
  \draw pic[draw,violet, "$\theta_1{+}\theta_2$", ->, angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius = 2.5cm] {angle = x--o--pr}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're right, it's working with your code. I must have had something strange on my end, where I found that `\draw pic[pic text options=...]` was working but not `\pic[pic text options=...]` I'll delete my comment!

Answer (score 7):

In this case I think that we can add options to the angle label by putting them after the quotted text like that :
`\draw pic[draw, "$\theta_2$"{option1,option2,...}, ->, angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius = 1.5cm] {angle = x--o--z2};`

**the code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
 \begin{scope}[thick,font=\scriptsize]
    \draw [->] (-.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node [above left]  {$\operatorname{Re} z$};
    \draw [->] (0,-.5) -- (0,4) node [below right] {$\operatorname{Im} z$};
  \end{scope}
  \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (z1) at (4.511,1.642);
  \coordinate (z2) at (2.143,2.553);
  \coordinate (pr) at (1.368,3.759);
  \coordinate (x) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (y) at (0,1);
  \draw (o) -- node[above,shift={(.4cm,.1cm)}] {$r_1$} (z1) node [right] {$z_1$};
  \draw (o) -- node[above,yshift=.2cm] {$r_2$} (z2) node [right] {$z_2$};
  \draw (o) -- node[above,yshift=1cm] {$r_1{\cdot}r_2$} (pr) node [right] {$z_1\cdot z_2$};
  \draw pic[draw, "$\theta_1$", ->, angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius = 1cm] {angle = x--o--z1}; 
  \draw pic[ draw,->,blue, "$\theta_2$"{shift=(80:0.35),inner sep=1pt, circle,draw},angle eccentricity=1.1,angle radius = 1.5cm] {angle = x--o--z2}; 
  \draw pic[draw, "$\theta_1{+}\theta_2$", ->, angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius = 2.5cm] {angle = x--o--pr}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 very nice solution

Comment: @AndréC Thank you

Comment: Nice! Couldn't work out how to adapt `"$\theta$"shift=(80:0.35)` to my case, but discovered that something like `"$\theta$"{xshift=6pt,yshift=-15pt}` also works.

Answer (score 3):

Let us move labels by hand.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,thick]
\draw[->] (-.5,0)--(2.5,0) node[below]{\rm{Re}$z$};
\draw[->] (0,-.5)--(0,3) node[left]{\rm{Im}$z$};
\def\aone{20} \def\atwo{45}
\def\rone{2}  \def\rtwo{1.6}
\draw 
(0,0)--(\aone:\rone) 
node[pos=.8,below]{$r_1$} node[right]{$z_1$} 
(0,0)--(\atwo:\rtwo) 
node[pos=.65,left]{$r_2$} node[above]{$z_2$}
(0,0)--(\aone+\atwo:\rone*\rtwo) 
node[pos=.65,left]{$r_1\cdot r_2$} node[right]{$z_1\cdot z_2$};
\draw[->,red] (0:.5) arc(0:\aone:.5) 
node[pos=.55,right]{$\theta_1$};
\draw[->,blue] (0:.8) arc(0:\atwo:.8) 
node[pos=.75,right]{$\theta_2$};
\draw[->,magenta] (0:1.2) arc(0:\aone+\atwo:1.2)
node[pos=.55,right]{$\theta_1+\theta_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the angle line as before without label and create a separate label for the angle `z1--o--z2`. You get

[image]

with the code

```
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
 \begin{scope}[thick,font=\scriptsize]
    \draw [->] (-.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node [above left]  {$\operatorname{Re} z$};
    \draw [->] (0,-.5) -- (0,4) node [below right] {$\operatorname{Im} z$};
  \end{scope}
  \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (z1) at (4.511,1.642);
  \coordinate (z2) at (2.143,2.553);
  \coordinate (pr) at (1.368,3.759);
  \coordinate (x) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (y) at (0,1);
  \draw (o) -- node[above,shift={(.4cm,.1cm)}] {$r_1$} (z1) node [right] {$z_1$};
  \draw (o) -- node[above,yshift=.2cm] {$r_2$} (z2) node [right] {$z_2$};
  \draw (o) -- node[above,yshift=1cm] {$r_1{\cdot}r_2$} (pr) node [right] {$z_1\cdot z_2$};
  \draw pic[draw, "$\theta_1$", ->, angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius = 1cm] {angle = x--o--z1}; 
  \draw pic[draw,  ->, angle eccentricity=0.8,angle radius = 1.5cm] {angle = x--o--z2}; 
  \draw pic[draw, "$\theta_1{+}\theta_2$", ->, angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius = 2.5cm] {angle = x--o--pr}; 
  \tkzLabelAngle[ pos = 1.2](z1,o,z2){$\theta_2$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `tkz-euclide` is not a tool adapted to this kind of problem but as it was one of the tags I allow myself to give an answer.
As some people prefer to use the `TikZ` options I have added in the next version I am currently using (4.2) the macro `TikZPicAngle` which allows to mark an angle with the `TikZ` options.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \tkzInit[xmin=0,ymin=0,xmax=5,ymax=5]
  \tkzDrawX[noticks,above=4pt,label={$\operatorname{Re} z$} ]
  \tkzDrawY[noticks,right=4pt,label={$\operatorname{Im} z$}]
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/o,4.511/1.642/z1,2.143/2.553/z2,
              1.368/3.759/pr,1/0/x,0/1/y}
  \tkzDrawSegments(o,z1 o,z2 o,pr)
  \tkzMarkAngle[->,size=1](x,o,z1)
  \tkzMarkAngle[->,size=2](x,o,z2)
  \tkzMarkAngle[->,size=3](x,o,pr)
  \tkzLabelAngle[dist=1.3](x,o,z1){$\theta_1$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[dist=2.3](z1,o,z2){$\theta_2$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[dist=3.2,right](x,o,pr){$\theta_1+\theta_2$}
  \tkzLabelSegment[pos=1.1,below](o,z1){$z_1$}
  \tkzLabelSegment[above=-1pt](o,z1){$r_1$}
  \tkzLabelSegment[pos=1.2,below](o,z2){$z_2$}
  \tkzLabelSegment[above=2pt](o,z2){$r_2$}
  \tkzLabelSegment[pos=1.2,below](o,pr){$z_1\cdot z_2$}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tzhelplines(5,4)
\tzaxes(-.5,-.5)(5.5,4.5){$\operatorname{Re} z$}[al]{$\operatorname{Im} z$}[br]
\tzcoors(0,0)(o)(4.511,1.642)(z1)(2.143,2.553)(z2)(1.368,3.759)(pr)(1,0)(x)(0,1)(y);
\tzline(o){$r_1$}[a,pos=0.6](z1){$z_1$}[r]
\tzline(o)(z2){$z_2$}[r]
\tzline(o){$r1\!\cdot\!r2$}[near end,al=-3pt](pr){$z_1\!\cdot\!z_2$}[r]
\tzanglemark[->](x)(o)(z1){$\theta_1$}[pos=1.25](1cm)
\tzanglemark[->](x)(o)(z2){$\theta_2$}[pos=1.1,yshift=7pt,red](1.5cm) % label moved
\tzanglemark[->](x)(o)(pr){$\theta_1+\theta_2$}[pos=1.25](2.5cm)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```