# How can I position node anchor exactly?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

So I have the following tikz code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \path (O) -- ++(4,0) coordinate (B);
    \path[name path=l1] (O) -- ++(40:10);
    \path[name path=l2] (B) -- ++(120:10);
    
    \draw [name intersections={of=l1 and l2, by=A}]
    (O) -- (A) node[midway, above left] {$a$} -- (B) -- cycle node[midway, below] {$b$};
    
    \draw (O) ++(0.5,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=40, radius=0.5] node[above right, midway] {$\theta$};
    \node[left] at (O) {$O$};
    \node[above] at (A) {$A$};
    \node[right] at (B) {$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here, the theta label is being covered by the line OA. This is a problem because it doesn't look very good. I want to put it lower down so that it is no longer being covered. However the only other "direction" I can put on the node is `right`, which will cause the theta label to be covered by the line OB. How can I set the direction or anchor such that it is now exactly between the two lines?

Comment: Maybe use `pos` key (replace `midway` with `pos=0.1` looks reasonably good in this particular case), but there might be a better solution. (actually it looks like that everything uses manual specification anyway. E.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34640/best-way-to-create-this-image-square-and-angle / https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502638/move-label-of-an-angle-in-tikz )

Comment: There's also [Label angle with tikz - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20826/label-angle-with-tikz) for alternative methods (doesn't look the same).

Comment: @user202729 I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did two things: I changed `above right` to `right` and I added a `\strut` to the `\theta` node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \path (O) -- ++(4,0) coordinate (B);
    \path[name path=l1] (O) -- ++(40:10);
    \path[name path=l2] (B) -- ++(120:10);
    
    \draw [name intersections={of=l1 and l2, by=A}]
    (O) -- (A) node[midway, above left] {$a$} -- (B) -- cycle node[midway, below] {$b$};
    
    \draw (O) ++(0.5,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=40, radius=0.5] 
      node[right,midway] {$\theta$\strut};
    \node[left] at (O) {$O$};
    \node[above] at (A) {$A$};
    \node[right] at (B) {$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want even more control, just add a bottom reaching `\rule` to the `\theta` to "push it up", as in

```
\draw (O) ++(0.5,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=40, radius=0.5] 
   node[right,midway] {$\theta$\rule[-6pt]{0pt}{0pt}};
```

[image]

Comment: What are the parameters of the `\rule` command?

Comment: @Kookie Can read LaTeX2e unofficial reference manual page 216 (chapter 23.8) for that.

Comment: @Kookie `\rule` paints a rectangle.  Parameters are `\rule[<depth>]{<width>}{<total height>}`