# Error with angle "shape" with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide, tikz-angles

I'm having trouble drawing angles with TikZ. It's strange because I've done this before, I even copied the code that I used, but the shape of the angle line is all wacky.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3, > = Straight Barb, trig format = rad]
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){o}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,0){x}
    \tkzDefPoint(0.7071,0.7071){a}
    \draw[thick, black, ->] (-1.5, 0) -- (1.5, 0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[thick, black, ->] (0, -1.5) -- (0, 1.5) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[thick, blue] plot [domain=0:4.7124, smooth, variable = \x, samples = 200] ({cos(\x)},{sin(\x)});
     \fill [yellow, opacity = 0.1, domain=0:4.7124, smooth, variable=\x, samples = 200]
      (0,0)
      -- plot ({cos(\x)}, {sin(\x)})
      -- (0, -1)
      -- cycle;
    \path[black, thick] (1,0) node[below] {$4$};
    \path[black, thick] (0,1) node[anchor = south west] {$4$};
    \draw[thick, red](0, 0) -- (0.7071, 0.7071) node[sloped, pos = 0.5, allow upside down]{\arrowIn};
    \draw[thick, red, dotted] (0.7071, 0.7071) -- (1,1);
    \draw pic[draw, black, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=20] {angle=x--o--a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The code is giving me this
[image]

No matter how I change the eccentricity and radius it never changes. I've tried changing "x--o--a" to "a--o--x" too. I'm trying to make it as an arrow too. I saw this [topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502638/move-label-of-an-angle-in-tikz) and tried their code but it's getting messed up anyway. What do I do?

Edit: I should mention, changing the eccentricity seems to change de position of the theta. I also figured out making it an arrow (pretty obvious to be honest, sorry.)

Comment: There is a simpler code to your figure with pure TikZ code. You don't need to use `plot` since you only need a simple `(1,0) arc (0:270:1cm) -- (0,0) -- cycle`.

Comment: Minor note: the syntax `arc (<angle>:<angle>:<radius>)` - used in several answers - is old syntax. The new syntax is `arc[start angle=<angle>, end angle=<angle>, radius=<radius]`.

Comment: @Sigur I'm the same - I get stuck in my ways; and then people cut-and-paste from old answers so old syntax sticks around longer than it should, which is why I leave little comments like this one.

Comment: Why use tkz-euclide to simply define points. It's not necessary here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`angles` does not work with `trig format=rad`.
You can change it back to `deg` for this one `\draw` like this:

```
\draw pic[draw, black, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=20, trig format=deg] {angle=x--o--a};
```

You do not really need `rad` format for this figure and I would not recommend drawing circles and arcs with plots. -it generates many small line/curve segments that takes more compile time and gives worse output.

-see answer by @Sigur

Answer (score 4):

This code is simpler, using `arc` and polar coordinates `(angle:radius)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3, > = Straight Barb] 
  \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (x) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (a) at (0.7071,0.7071);
  \draw[thick, black, ->] (-1.5, 0) -- (1.5, 0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[thick, black, ->] (0, -1.5) -- (0, 1.5) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw[fill=green, fill opacity = 0.1] (1,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=270, radius=1cm] -- (0,0) -- cycle;
  \draw[thick, blue] (1,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=270, radius=1cm];
  \path[black, thick] (1,0) node[below] {$4$};
  \path[black, thick] (0,1) node[anchor = south west] {$4$};
  \draw[thick, red, ->](0, 0) -- (45:1cm);
  \draw[thick, red, dotted] (45:1cm) -- (1,1);
  \draw pic[draw, black, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.25, angle radius=.6cm] {angle=x--o--a};    
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't have much practice with the arc operation. Is there a way of doing this without using it?

Comment: @TulioAlves, well, since what you need is an arc of circle I think that it is the best approach. Use a plot construction is strange to me.

Comment: I got used to it because I was plotting a lot of different functions, and I will continue to do so. I don't really know how I would draw them without using plot, that's why I asked. I'll look into it.

Comment: @TulioAlves, maybe your code could be fixed if you pass the unit to the angle radius. See what I used `.6cm`.

Comment: Doesn't really change anything sadly...

Comment: @TulioAlves, I'm not sure but I suspect that `trig format = rad` could change a lot the construction. So I prefer degrees.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is some conflict (as @hpekristiansen pointed in his answer: the library `angles` does not work with the option `trig format=rad` ). If `pgf` or `tkz-euclide` are not really needed, then don't load them.

In my opinion, we should code as plain as possible!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,thick]
\path 
(0,0) coordinate (o)
(1,0) coordinate (x) node[below right] {$4$}
(0,1) node[above left] {$4$}
(1,1) coordinate (a);
\fill[yellow,opacity=.2] (0,0)--(1,0) arc(0:270:1)--cycle;
\path pic[draw,-stealth,"$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.3, angle radius=20] {angle=x--o--a};
\draw[red,dotted] (0,0)--(1,1);
\draw[->] (-1.25, 0) -- (1.5, 0) node[above left] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0, -1.25) -- (0, 1.5) node[below right] {$y$};
\draw[blue] (0,0) circle(1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution if you need to compile with pdflatex.
A comment on tkz-euclide: I don't think it's necessary to use it just to define points or draw angles. It's preferable either to use only TikZ or only tkz-euclide. The mix is unpleasant in terms of syntax.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
   \tkzDefPoint(0, 4){A}
   \tkzDefPoint(0, -4){B}
   \tkzDefPoint(4, 0){C}
   \tkzDefPoint(45:4){F}
   \tkzDefPoint(45:4.8){F'}
   \tkzInit[xmin=-4.5,xmax=4.5,ymin=-4.5,ymax=4.5]
   \tkzDrawX[thick,right=0.5em]
   \tkzDrawY[thick,above=0.5em]
   \tkzLabelPoint[below](C){$4$}
   \tkzLabelPoint[above right](A){$4$}
   \tkzDrawArc[thick,color=blue](O,C)(B)
   \tkzDrawSector[fill=yellow, opacity = 0.1](O,C)(B)
   \tkzDrawSegments[thick,-stealth,red](O,F)
   \tkzDrawSegments[thick,red,dotted](F,F')
   \tkzMarkAngle[black,-stealth,size=1.5](C,O,F)
   \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.25](C,O,F){\theta}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I've taken over much of the code from pascal974. I don't think tkz-elements is very useful in this case, but congratulations on trying it out.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The original post uses `tkz-euclide`, I propose a solution with this package and `tkz-elements`.

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655544/error-with-angle-shape-with-tikz/655547#655547
\usepackage{tkz-elements}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tkzelements}
  z.O = point: new (0, 0)
  z.A = point: new (0, 4)
  z.B = point: new (0, -4)
  z.C = point: new (4, 0)
  z.F = point: polar (4, math.pi/4)
  z.Fp = point: polar (4.8, math.pi/4)
\end{tkzelements}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzSetUpStyle[postaction=decorate,
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[thick]{#1}}
      }]{myarrow}
  \tkzGetNodes
  % with tkz-base
  \tkzInit[xmin=-4.5,xmax=4.5,ymin=-4.5,ymax=4.5,]
  \tkzDrawX[thick,right=0.5em]
  \tkzDrawY[thick,above=0.5em]
  \tkzLabelPoint[below](C){$4$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[above right](A){$4$}
  % with tkz-euclide
  \tkzDrawArc[thick,color=blue](O,C)(B)
  \tkzDrawSector[fill=yellow, opacity = 0.1](O,C)(B)
  % 
  \tkzDrawSegments[thick,myarrow={Straight Barb},red](O,F)
  \tkzDrawSegments[thick,red,dotted](F,F')%<-- Fp in tkzelements, F' in tikzpicture
  %
  \tkzPicAngle[
    "$\theta$",
    draw=black,
    ->,>={Straight Barb},
    angle eccentricity=1.3,
    angle radius=1cm
  ](C,O,F)
  % \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,F,F')%
  % \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,F,F')%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A brave attempt at tkz-elements! New version this weekend! but I don't think it's necessary as the figure only requires drawings and no calculation of coordinates.

Comment: @Alain Matthes I admit that when faced with a new gift, I wanted to try it. For the arrow on the angle mark, I have no excuse...